# HSQLDB: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, hsqldb

I have found this error has arised many times throughout the internet but I haven't found a solution for my case at all. I have an HSQL database - I have connected to one table in my database successfully. I went on to create another table in the database - with exactly the same Java code modified as appropriate however it brings up the error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: USER.

I found that in my file store script the code for the PRODUCT table create was there however I have created the USER table the same way I did with the PRODUCT table - using the HSQL Database Manager.

This is my error code:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: USER
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at hb00294_eCommerce_com1028.data.LoginWindow.validateUserDetails(LoginWindow.java:129)
    at hb00294_eCommerce_com1028.data.LoginWindow.access$4(LoginWindow.java:121)
    at hb00294_eCommerce_com1028.data.LoginWindow$2.mouseClicked(LoginWindow.java:113)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: USER
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 37 more
```

This is my file store script:

```
SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB4D9B227D23
SET DATABASE GC 0
SET DATABASE DEFAULT RESULT MEMORY ROWS 0
SET DATABASE EVENT LOG LEVEL 0
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS
SET DATABASE DEFAULT ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION ROLLBACK ON CONFLICT TRUE
SET DATABASE TEXT TABLE DEFAULTS ''
SET DATABASE SQL NAMES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL REFERENCES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL SIZE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TYPES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC DELETE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC UPDATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONCAT NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL UNIQUE NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONVERT TRUNCATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL AVG SCALE 0
SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN TRUE
SET FILES WRITE DELAY 500 MILLIS
SET FILES BACKUP INCREMENT TRUE
SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000
SET FILES CACHE ROWS 50000
SET FILES SCALE 32
SET FILES LOB SCALE 32
SET FILES DEFRAG 0
SET FILES NIO TRUE
SET FILES NIO SIZE 256
SET FILES LOG TRUE
SET FILES LOG SIZE 50
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD DIGEST 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
ALTER USER SA SET LOCAL TRUE
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.PRODUCT(ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,TITLE VARCHAR(50),DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(90),INFORMATION VARCHAR(200),TYPE VARCHAR(50),PRICE DOUBLE,SHIPPINGPRICE DOUBLE)
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.PRODUCT ALTER COLUMN ID RESTART WITH 15
ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 1
SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_IDENTIFIER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TIME_STAMP TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CARDINAL_NUMBER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_DATA TO PUBLIC
GRANT DBA TO SA
SET SCHEMA SYSTEM_LOBS
INSERT INTO BLOCKS VALUES(0,2147483647,0)
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES(1,'a','b','c','MISCELLANEOUS',4.0E0,4.0E0)
```

I'm not sure whether it is a problem with access permissions or that it does not recognise that the USER table exists - I have created a method to show all table names within the database and it does show PRODUCT but not USER. Any suggestions to solve this?

I hope I have provided enough information - please let me know if there is any further information required and I really appreciate any help given.

Comment: i can't see any `create table user...`. Please post the sql for the user table

Comment: OP, did you figure this out. I have the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually create a table named USER, it will show up in the .script file alongside the other tables.

It is possible that you did create the table in a later session but did not SHUTDOWN the database or perform a CHECKPOINT, so the extra CREATE TABLE USER ... statement was not saved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using an in-memory instance `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:invoice` for a unit test (See the **:mem** in the jdbc URL).
I was trying to execute the following script (DDL/Creation + DML/Inserts):

```sql
DROP TABLE Item IF EXISTS;
DROP TABLE Invoice IF EXISTS;
DROP TABLE Product IF EXISTS;
DROP TABLE Customer IF EXISTS;
CREATE TABLE Customer(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,FirstName VARCHAR(20),LastName VARCHAR(30),Street VARCHAR(50),City VARCHAR(25));
CREATE TABLE Product(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,Name VARCHAR(30),Price DECIMAL);
CREATE TABLE Invoice(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,CustomerID INTEGER,Total DECIMAL, FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES Customer(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE);
CREATE TABLE Item(InvoiceID INTEGER,Item INTEGER,ProductID INTEGER,Quantity INTEGER,Cost DECIMAL,PRIMARY KEY(InvoiceID,Item), FOREIGN KEY (InvoiceId) REFERENCES Invoice (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (ProductId) REFERENCES Product(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE);
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(0,'Laura','Steel','429 Seventh Av.','Dallas');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES(0,'Iron Iron',54);
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(1,'Susanne','King','366 - 20th Ave.','Olten');
```

To make it work I split the DDL and DML into two scripts, the unit test ended  in something like this:

```java
class Ch15JdbcTest {

  public static final String JDBC_HSQLDB_URL = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:invoice";

  @BeforeEach
  void setup() throws IOException {
    try (var connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_HSQLDB_URL);
        var statement = connection.createStatement()) {
      var create = Files.readString(Path.of("src/test/resources/ch15jdbc/create_invoicedb.sql"));
      statement.execute(create);
      var data = Files.readString(Path.of("src/test/resources/ch15jdbc/data_invoicedb.sql"));
      statement.execute(data);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  @Test
  void verifyCount() {
    try (var connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_HSQLDB_URL);
        var statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT count(*) FROM Product");
        var result = statement.executeQuery()) {

      result.next();
      int productCount = result.getInt(1);

      assertThat(productCount).isEqualTo(50);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

The source code is available [here](https://github.com/JuanMorenoDeveloper/java-17-certification-practice/blob/2f6664d60d2cc9f37841ab376fd1f0b3f03800dd/src/test/java/ve/com/proitcsolution/Ch15JdbcTest.java#L14-L14).